# Using OpenCV to track a object, how do i minimize searching area, while not decreasing overall picture?

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi3

I'm using **OpenCv** to track a steel ball in a project, using a `raspberry PI3b+` and a `raspicam v2.1`.

To decrease computational time it would be great to minimize the area searched between each frame.

Is there a function in OpenCV that can focus the searching area on a region surrounding the last given position of the steel ball instead of the whole frame?

Comment: Use ROI concept, draw a rectangle using opencv and pass the image inside rectangle only to function that does the tracking

Comment: Thank you, i will look into it!